# Proving inequality with absolute value

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

How can I show the following inequality for any real numbers $x,y,z$?

$$\frac{|x-z|}{1+|x-z|}\le \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} + \frac{|y-z|}{1+|y-z|}.$$

The triangle inequality could be useful, but I am not sure in what way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
 \frac{x}{1+x}
 = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + x}.
$$
So by using the triangle inequality we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{|x-z|}{1 + |x-z|}
&\leq 1 - \frac{1}{1 + |x-z|}
\leq 1 - \frac{1}{1 + |x-y| + |y-z|} \\
&= \frac{|x-y| + |y-z|}{1 + |x-y| + |y-z|}
= \frac{|x-y|}{1 + |x-y| + |y-z|} + \frac{|y-z|}{1 + |x-y| + |y-z|} \\
&\leq \frac{|x-y|}{1 + |x-y|} + \frac{|y-z|}{1 + |y-z|}.
\end{align*}